# How to route mywebsite.com/filename to some action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating file downloading backend in asp.net core 3.1 and I want to enter file name after my site name (for example [www.something.com/file_txt](http://www.something.com/file_txt)) to get redirected to home controller and file action method with string filename as parameter. In that action method I will then open file.txt and send it as response to user. Idea is to get some file without entering something long like [www.something.com/home/file/image_jpg](http://www.something.com/home/file/image_jpg)

Is that possible in asp.net core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. something like this

```
    [Route("/{filename}")]
    public IActionResult File(string filename)
    {
        //return file here. you have it's name in filename argument
    }
```